# Google play services won't run unless you update Google play services

Tags: stock-android, google-play-services

I am constantly getting a notification about every 1 or 5 minutes since I had updated the Google Play Services app. It's a very strange type of notification. It says "Google Play Services won't run unless you update Google Play Services". See the screenshot below :
[image]

What is the cause of this problem and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem myself, like this :
Previously, I had updated ***Google Play Services*** from an APK file. So, this time, instead of updating ***Google Play Services*** from an APK file, I had updated it from the Play Store, and the notification went away.
So, for some reason, updating the app from an APK file was causing the problem.

Comment: That's very much usual. Some system apps if updated from external apks, then show problems.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a different solution.  Find the the correct version for your phone, Google the APK, download it and install using APK handler.  Fixed the problem.